# SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] PHP Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I'm getting this error while I was implementing and testing PHP webservice using Zend Soap.

I'm testing the same codes under 2 different protocols(http & https) in 2 different web servers.
http site works just fine, but I get "SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch]..." error in https.

The two web servers almost have the same specs.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer. The error message is not actually representing the real problem as soap error types are limited to 5 types.

1. VersionMismatch
2. MustUnderstand
3. DataEncodingUnknown
4. Sender
5. Receiver

   There was a debugging code throwing text messages and it was just picking up this error type..silly